# Memory scope of List in Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, list, memory

I am writing a class in which I have a List. And I am instantiating the list from the run method of `Runnable`. As:

```
public void sendEmailToLegalUsers() {
    Log.info("JYM====================================");

    try {
        new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                userCns = new ArrayList<String>();
                recipients = new ArrayList<String>();

                ///other codes
            }
        };                  
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        Log.info("Error occurred in LDAPSendMail: "+ e.getMessage());
    }   

    Log.info("END====================================");
}
```

Now each time the sendEmailToLegalUsers method will be called there will be a new thread. Now I am wondering is the memory scope of the list is bounded to class level (if it is bounded to class level and if say this method is called two times then what will happen of the list which is created by Thread 1 when there is also a Thread 2) or as the threads run in their own scope then the list will have different scope for each thread. Is there any chance to mixup of the list data between two or multiple thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the same `Runnable` class for both of the threads then yes, there will be overlap.  If you have a separate `new Runnable()` for each of your threads then no, they will be separate list instances *but* this is only if the lists are defined to be local to the `Runnable`.  If the lists are defined in the calling class then the 2nd time you call your method, the `userCns` and `recipients` fields will be overwritten.

In your case, I don't see any threads being forked at all.  All I see is you instantiating the `Runnable`.  Are you sure you aren't trying to do something like:

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // lists are local to the runnable
            List<String> userCns = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> recipients = new ArrayList<String>();
           ///other codes
        }
    }).start();
```

In this case, each time you call your `sendEmailToLegalUsers()` method, a new `Runnable` will be created with new lists.

Answer (score 4):

You are creating a new pair of lists for each thread.  You should also make them local variables, otherwise you can get a thread safety issue, not on the lists but the references to the lists.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        List<String> userCns = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> recipients = new ArrayList<String>();

        ///other codes
    }
}).start();
```

If userCns or recipients are fields, they can be shared between thread because the field is shared.

Answer (score 0):

If multiple threads calling same `run()`, yes there is chance for wrong results because list is instance scope and both threads operate on same list.

If you create new Runnable() for each thread, then they will have their own copy and they don't update each other data.

Answer (score 0):

You're createing a new Runnable, but not doing anything with it - you're certainly not creating a new Thread.

However, if you were to pass the created Runnables to a thread then the references would be restricted to the Runnable instance.